# Можно ли описать массив объектов длиной в варианты типов?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, типы

У меня есть структура вроде этой:

```
export const GENDER: IFieldListsAssociation = [
  { title: 'Не выбрано', value: null, checked: true },
  { title: 'Мужской', value: 'male' },
  { title: 'Женский', value: 'female' }
];
```

`IFieldListsAssociation`  по сути описывает обязательное наличие `title` и `value` и не обязательный `checked`.

Далее: есть тип который хранит все доступные `value`, собственно `null | 'male' | 'female'`

Идея состоит в том, что бы создать генерик, для `IFieldListsAssociation` который бы на основе этих типов, требовал бы идентичное количество объектов в массиве. В идеале, если такое возможно, как в данном случае все 3 объекта и три разных `value` соответственно. Загвоздка для меня в том, что для объектов, как подобное реализовать понимаю, но как подобное сделать для массива, даже не знаю откуда начать копать.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге было выбрано такое решение:

```
// Создание "тульпы" нужной длины
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/59906630/5526192
type ArrayLengthMutationKeys = 'splice' | 'push' | 'pop' | 'shift' | 'unshift';
type FixedLengthArray<T, L extends number, TObj = [T, ...Array<T>]> = Pick<
  TObj,
  Exclude<keyof TObj, ArrayLengthMutationKeys>
> & {
  readonly length: L;
  [I: number]: T;
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => IterableIterator<T>;
};


// Преобразование входящего типа в тульпу для нахождения длины
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/5526192
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void
  ? I
  : never;
type LastOf<T> = UnionToIntersection<T extends any ? () => T : never> extends () => infer R
  ? R
  : never;

// TS4.0+
type Push<T extends any[], V> = [...T, V];

// TS4.1+
type TuplifyUnion<T, L = LastOf<T>, N = [T] extends [never] ? true : false> = true extends N
  ? []
  : Push<TuplifyUnion<Exclude<T, L>>, L>;

export interface IFieldListAssociation<T> {
  checked?: boolean;
  value: T;
  title: string;
}

export type IFieldListsAssociation<T> = FixedLengthArray<
  IFieldListAssociation<T>,
  // Выдает ошибку Type 'TuplifyUnion<T, LastOf<T>, [T] extends [never] ? true : false>["length"]' does not satisfy the constraint 'number'.
  // Но работает в итоге корректно. Идей как это забороть - нет
  // @ts-ignore
  TuplifyUnion<T>['length']
>;

type Gender = 'male' | 'female';

/**
 * Пресет списка выбора пола.
 */
export const GENDER: IFieldListsAssociation<Gender | null> = [
  { title: 'Не выбрано', value: null, checked: true },
  { title: 'Мужской', value: 'male' },
  { title: 'Женский', value: 'female' }
];
```

Плюсы: Ограничивает количество создаваемых элементов, не дает ввести не правильное значение, поддерживает `boolean`, можно по ситуации дополнять типы (вроде `Gender | null`), любой порядок элементов;

Минусы: можно ввести 2 одинаковых значения, но тут уже думаю нужно иметь не совсем прямые руки что бы так сделать;

Был набросок того, что бы можно было ввести только уникальные значения `value`, но тогда нет возможности задавать нужную очередность, а так как типы генерируются с схемы graphql, исправить исходный тип под нужную очерёдность не получится. К тому же не получалось привести присваиваемый объект к нужному типу, линтер ругался, но вариант тоже работал.

Если будут более "приятное" решение, буду рад его поставить ответом